# No Internet Access Sometimes on Windows 7 But Skype Always Works

Tags: internet-connection

I recently ran into a problem where my browsers sometimes **suddenly** have no internet access, but then my Skype is active and messages pops out and the internet icon displayed that I have internet access. I cannot download and cannot browse the internet even the address: `localhost/` (I use XAMPP to setup my local server for testings). Also my torrents seems to work. I need to restart my PC to access the internet.

The diagnose says they cannot find any problem. So in conclusion, I cannot access: local server on my pc, websites, adapter's settings page: `setup.net`, direct downloads and so on. BUT HAVE CONNECTIONS on Skype and torrents??!!

Please Help! What is the problem my computer goes into? And how to fix it.

Comment: Did you check proxy settings for browser especially in IE?

Comment: If you cannot access localhost you have a serious system corruption considering localhost is the local pc and is available when your connected to any network.  Pipe the output of `ipconfig /all` into a text file, remove any public ip address, and post the contents.

Comment: @Ramhound I will try if I run into the problem again

Comment: @DanielCheung - What do you mean if you ran in the problem again?  I thought you currently had this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS is flaky. Skype connects through an IP address, so doesn't need DNS services to work. Your browser needs DNS to resolve hostnames.

Try setting your DNS servers to Google's: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Update: Since you also mentioned torrents, torrent client can open a lot of sockets, and make your router sick. Try and see if you can reproduce the problem with your torrent client shut down.

Comment: Thanks. Mine was the best answer of course, since it was the only one there :D

Comment: anyway, my computer fixed itself, but applying Google's DNS was no use